# source code files with weird line endings

Tags: perforce, line-endings

I have noticed that some .Net code committed by a new contracting team has strange line endings.  When I do a hex dump of the files I see that each line ends with 2 carriage returns (0d) and 1 line feed (0a).

When viewed in Visual Studio it looks like every code line has an empty line after it, which looks very odd.

What can cause this?  It it some strange IDE?  Could it be caused by Perforce?  (I got the code out by syncing a Perforce workspace).

The only time I've ever seen non-standard line endings before is when people copy/paste code from a web page, email, or chat window.  Could that be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

If they submitted Windows-style (CRLF) line endings but used the `unix` (LF) LineEnd setting in their client workspaces, then the files would have an extra CR as part of each line, and a Windows machine would sync them down as CRCRLF.  That's the most likely explanation for what you're seeing.

The ideal way to fix this is just for everyone to use a LineEnd that matches their environment (usually the default of `local` works just fine for this), but if someone needs to use a mix of tools/platforms within a single workspace, switching to the `share` LineEnd option will force everything to be normalized on submit by stripping all the CRs.  (This also makes it impossible to submit text files with actual CR characters, but that's *usually* not a big deal -- for files where you don't want any sort of transformation to occur, use the `binary` filetype.)

Comment: Is that seriously how Perforce handles things? Because other CVSes have been able to deal with mixed line endings in non-destructive ways for at least a decade.

Comment: @Taschi, git is certainly not guilt-free in this area.  It may be just that it's a hard problem